# .Net Mvc application Hosting

Tags: .net

I create a Shopping site on .net mvc with sql database. I can't understand what hosting we need for access this application on internet.

I confused for purchasing
1.Window Server hosting.
2.godaddy hosting

Please suggest me for hosting this site what thinks we need. Thanku

Comment: Other option is Azure

Comment: If you are using .net, then my recommendation go with Windows Server. Although .net core has been supported on Windows, but I prefer use Windows Server. Don't use Godaddy for hosting, not too good. For .net hosting, check out Asphostportal.com and also Hostforlife.eu if you are looking for EU data center

Answer (score -1):

Please go for window server hosting. As per my knowledge godaddy doesnot support MVC4. You can go for service provider like hostgator. Also before going for any service just check which version of MVC they support. Few provider does not support MVC5 due to security concern.

Comment: This answer is making a huge amount of assumptions that end up making it mostly useless. What makes you think OP needs MVC4 ? What makes you think GoDaddy doesn't support it ? (That's nothing but a framework after all). Also _As per my knowledge_ with no source is definitely frowned upon.

Comment: i have already faced this issue earlier, MVC 4 introduced with some dlls which they does not allow stated that they(godaddy) blocked those dlls due to security concerns

Comment: Maybe you have some source/links that you could provide to support this claim ?